# How to see "people nearby" with Empathy in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, empathy

Empaty lost "people nearby" option in Ubuntu 14.04.

So: How to configure **empathy** in **Ubuntu 14.04** in order to chat with people in the local area network?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04 the messaging account management is done via the 'Online Accounts' panel. You can either open Empathy and select 'Accounts' or open 'System Settings' and go directly to 'Online Accounts'. In the 'Online Accounts' panel choose the 'Add account' option and select to create a new account for the 'Salut' service. This enables the known 'People Nearby' account in Empathy on Ubuntu 14.04 using the 'Salut' protocol.

See:

- https://help.gnome.org/users/empathy/stable/create-account.html.en
- https://help.gnome.org/users/empathy/stable/salut-protocol.html.en